# providerのnotifyListeners()で再描画させたいのですができません。（同じ内容を他質問サイトに投稿させていただいております）

Tags: ios, android, flutter, dart

Flutterの勉強で、メモ帳アプリを作成しています。
そこでshowModalBottomSheetWidgetをproviderのnotifyListeners()で再描画させたいのですができません。
何が足りないのでしょうか？
よければアドバイスいただけるとありがたいです。
よろしくお願いします。

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class SendDiary extends StatefulWidget {
  String? destination;
  SendDiary(this.destination);

  @override
  State<SendDiary> createState() => _SendDiary();
}

class _SendDiary extends State<SendDiary> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double deviceHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final double deviceWdth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
        body: TextButton(
      onPressed: () {
        showModalBottomSheet(
            isScrollControlled: true,
            context: context,
            enableDrag: true,
            builder: (context) {
              return Consumer<ReShowModalBottomSheet>(
                  builder: (context, model, child) {
                return Container(
                    height: deviceHeight * 0.4,
                    width: deviceWdth,
                    child: Column(children: [
                      TextButton(
//ここでメモ帳作成画面へ遷移
                        onPressed: () async {
                          await Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => WriteDiary(null)));
//メモ帳作成後、戻ってきたタイミングで再描画
                          model.reShowModalBottomSheet();
                        },
                        child: Text('新規メモ帳作成画面へ遷移'),
                      ),
                      SingleChildScrollView(
                          physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                          child: Column(children: [
                            for (int index = 0;
                                index < diaryStorage[0].length;
                                index++) ...{
                              // new Consumer<ReShowModalBottomSheet>(
                              //     builder: (context, model, child) {
                              new TextButton(
                                onPressed: () async {
//ここで保存していたメモ帳（下書き）をメモ帳作成画面へ展開
                                  await Navigator.push(
                                      context,
                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder: (context) => SendWriteDiary(
                                                null,
                                                null,
                                                null,
                                                'null',
                                                null,
                                              )));
//メモ帳作成画面から戻り、画面再描画
                                       model.reShowModalBottomSheet();
                                },
                                child: Text('下書きの数だけButtonを作成'),
                              )
                            }
                          ]))
                    ]));
              });
            });
      },
      child: Text('ShowModalBottomSheet'),
    ));
  }
}
```

＜ソースの説明＞
Buttonを押すとshowModalBottomSheetが表示され、そこに新規メモ帳作成Buttonと今までに作成した下書きのメモ帳が動的に表示させる、といった機能を実装しようといています。
しかし、新規メモ帳作成Buttonを押し、メモ帳作成画面へ移動したあとにメモ内容を保存し、「 Navigator.pop(context);」により戻るとnotifyListeners()が実行されても画面が再描画されません。

Comment: notifyListeners()の部分です。

Comment: import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ReShowModalBottomSheet extends ChangeNotifier {
  void reShowModalBottomSheet() {
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://qiita.com/yamada0088/questions/7bbe18508b80ccd0144b) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Comment: わかりました。アドバイスありがとうございます。